# Avoid a download after loading a page

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible do avoid downloading a document when the DOM is finish downloading ?

I tried many thing such as

> event.preventDefault(); or event.stopPropagation();

but it doesn't work.

Here is my code :

```
    jQuery(document).load(function(){
        event.stopPropagation();    
    });

    return '<tr class="data">' + '<td>' +  "<span><a href='#/groupama/project/" + id + "'>"+ nom + "<a href=" +  (window.location.href = "rest/groupama/export/bilan-projet/" + id) +">" + "<br><br><i>  télécharger le bilan" + "</a></span>" +
        '</td>' + '<td>' + '<span>' + projetVigireport + '</span>' + '</td>' + '<td>' + '<span>' + statutAffichage +
        '</span>' + '</td>' + '<td>' + '<span>' + version + '</span>' + '</td>' + '<td>' + '<span>' +
        chefDeProjetG2S + '</span>' + '</td>' + '<td>' + '<span>' + domaine + '</span>' + '</td>' + '<td>' +
        '<span>' + division + '</span>' + '</td>' + '<td>' + '<span>' + application + '</span>' + '</td>' + '<td>' +
        '<span>' + dateCommande + '</span>' + '</td>' + '<td>' + '<span>' + dateLancement + '</span>' + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + '<span>' +
        ((!demandeDateRecepProv && dateReceptionProvDemandee) ? '' : dateReceptionProvDemandee) + '</span>' +
        '</td>' + '<td>' + '<span>' +
        ((!demandeDateRecepProv && dateReceptionProvRevisee) ? '' : dateReceptionProvRevisee) + '</span>' +
        '</td>' + '<td>' + '<span>' +
        ((!demandeDateRecepProv && dateReceptionProvEffective) ? '' : dateReceptionProvEffective) + '</span>' +
        '</td>' + '<td>' + '<span>' + dateRecepDef + '</span>' + '</td>' + '<td>' + '<span>' + dureeGarantie +
        ' mois</span>' + '</td>' + '<td>' + '<span>' + dateFinGarantie + '</span>' + '</td>' + '<td>' + '<span>' +
        chargeRTU + '</span>' + '</td>' + '<td>' + '<span>' + chargeTotale + '</span>' + '</td>' + '<td>' +
        '<span>' + ((IQ1 == -1) ? '' : IQ1) + '</span>' + '</td>' + '<td>' + '<span>' + ((IQ2 == -1) ? '' : IQ2) +
        '</span>' + '</td>' + '<td>' + '<span>' + ((IQ3 == -1) ? '' : IQ3) + '</span>' + '</td>' + '<td>' +
        '<span>' + ((ID1 == -1) ? '' : ID1) + '</span>' + '</td>' + '<td>' + '<span>' + ((ID2 == -1) ? '' : ID2) +
        '</span>' + '</td>' + '<td>' + '<span>' + ((IC == -1) ? '' : IC) + '</span>' + '</td>' + '<td>' + '<span>' +
        ((IP1 == -1) ? '' : IP1) + '</span>' + '</td>' + '<td>' + '<span>' + ((IP2 == -1) ? '' : IP2) + '</span>' +
        '</td>' + '<td>' + '<span>' + (note) + '</span>' + '</td>' + '<td>' + '<span>' +
        (variable + '%') + '</span>' + '</td>' + '<td>' + '<span>' + montantHt + '</span>' +
        '</td>' + '<td>' + '<span>' + montantProvisionHt + '</span>' + '</td>' + '<td>' + '<span>' +
        montantPartVariableHt + '</span>' + '</td>' + '</tr>';`
```

So it returns a table with a link for each rows, where when i click it download the file for the corresponding row (thanks to `window.location.href = "rest/groupama/export/bilan-projet/" + id`). But the problems is that it also download the last row when the DOM is finish loading and I want to avoid it to do so.

Any idea how to avoid a download when the dom finished loading ?

Comment: remove the window.location.href from the a tag.  The link to the file will be enough.  You are telling it to go to that href when it loads.  '<a href="rest/groupama/export/bilan-projet/' + id) +'>'

Comment: oh yes it works ^^ thanks so much didn't think that could be the problem

Comment: (window.location.href = "rest/groupama/export/bilan-projet/" + id)   <-- makes no sense. You should just be building the url....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

location.href need to be removed because it executes immediately

```js
    return '<tr class="data">' + '<td>' +  "<span><a href='#/groupama/project/" + id + "'>"+ nom + "<a href='rest/groupama/export/bilan-projet/'><br><br><i>  télécharger le bilan" + "</a></span>" +
        '</td>' + '<td>' + '<span>' + projetVigireport + '</span>' + '</td>' + '<td>' + '<span>' + statutAffichage +
        '</span>' + '</td>' + '<td>' + '<span>' + version + '</span>' + '</td>' + '<td>' + '<span>' +
        chefDeProjetG2S + '</span>' + '</td>' + '<td>' + '<span>' + domaine + '</span>' + '</td>' + '<td>' +
        '<span>' + division + '</span>' + '</td>' + '<td>' + '<span>' + application + '</span>' + '</td>' + '<td>' +
        '<span>' + dateCommande + '</span>' + '</td>' + '<td>' + '<span>' + dateLancement + '</span>' + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + '<span>' +
        ((!demandeDateRecepProv && dateReceptionProvDemandee) ? '' : dateReceptionProvDemandee) + '</span>' +
        '</td>' + '<td>' + '<span>' +
        ((!demandeDateRecepProv && dateReceptionProvRevisee) ? '' : dateReceptionProvRevisee) + '</span>' +
        '</td>' + '<td>' + '<span>' +
        ((!demandeDateRecepProv && dateReceptionProvEffective) ? '' : dateReceptionProvEffective) + '</span>' +
        '</td>' + '<td>' + '<span>' + dateRecepDef + '</span>' + '</td>' + '<td>' + '<span>' + dureeGarantie +
        ' mois</span>' + '</td>' + '<td>' + '<span>' + dateFinGarantie + '</span>' + '</td>' + '<td>' + '<span>' +
        chargeRTU + '</span>' + '</td>' + '<td>' + '<span>' + chargeTotale + '</span>' + '</td>' + '<td>' +
        '<span>' + ((IQ1 == -1) ? '' : IQ1) + '</span>' + '</td>' + '<td>' + '<span>' + ((IQ2 == -1) ? '' : IQ2) +
        '</span>' + '</td>' + '<td>' + '<span>' + ((IQ3 == -1) ? '' : IQ3) + '</span>' + '</td>' + '<td>' +
        '<span>' + ((ID1 == -1) ? '' : ID1) + '</span>' + '</td>' + '<td>' + '<span>' + ((ID2 == -1) ? '' : ID2) +
        '</span>' + '</td>' + '<td>' + '<span>' + ((IC == -1) ? '' : IC) + '</span>' + '</td>' + '<td>' + '<span>' +
        ((IP1 == -1) ? '' : IP1) + '</span>' + '</td>' + '<td>' + '<span>' + ((IP2 == -1) ? '' : IP2) + '</span>' +
        '</td>' + '<td>' + '<span>' + (note) + '</span>' + '</td>' + '<td>' + '<span>' +
        (variable + '%') + '</span>' + '</td>' + '<td>' + '<span>' + montantHt + '</span>' +
        '</td>' + '<td>' + '<span>' + montantProvisionHt + '</span>' + '</td>' + '<td>' + '<span>' +
        montantPartVariableHt + '</span>' + '</td>' + '</tr>';`
```